# Why does a submit button pass null data from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm very new to C# and MVC and this may look like a basic question, but even after thorougly searching for people with simmilar problems I can't make this to work.

The problem is on a submit button I have on an Edit View that for some reason pass null data to the Update method instead of the form input data.

This is the view:

```
<div class="row-fluid metro">
<div class="span2 offset4">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Realty", FormMethod.Post))
    {

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Details)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Manager)
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Details</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Details)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Details)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Manager</label>
            <div class="controls">
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Manager.Id, Model.Managers)

               </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Realty")"><button type="button" class="btn">Cancelar</button></a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

this is the viewmodel
    public class RealtyViewModel
    {
        /// 
        /// Gets or sets the id.
        /// 
        public int Id { get; set; }

```
    public string Address { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the details.
    /// </summary>
    public string Details { get; private set; }
    public List<HomeViewModel> Homes { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the manager.
    /// </summary>





    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Managers { get; set; }

    public ManagerViewModel Manager { get; private set; }
    public RealtyViewModel(int id,string Address, string Details, ManagerViewModel Manager)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.Details = Details;
        this.Manager = Manager;
    }

    public RealtyViewModel() {}

}
```

}

And finnally, this is the Update method from the controller if needed:

```
            public ActionResult Update(RealtyViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.Id == 0)
        {
            var manager = this.managerService.Get(model.Manager.Id);
            this.realtyService.Create(model.Address, model.Details,manager);
        }
        else
        {
            var manager = this.managerService.Get(model.Manager.Id);
            this.realtyService.Update(model.Id,model.Address, model.Details, manager);
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
         public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> managers = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var model = new RealtyViewModel();

        if (id != 0)
        {
            var realty = this.realtyService.Get(id);
            var mvm = new ManagerViewModel(realty.Manager.Id, realty.Manager.Name, realty.Manager.Age);
            model = new RealtyViewModel(realty.Id, realty.Address, realty.Details, mvm);
        }
        foreach (var Manager in managerService.GetAll())
        {
            managers.Add(new SelectListItem { Value=Manager.Id.ToString(),Text=Manager.Name});
        }
        model.Managers = managers;
        return this.View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Does debugger enters into your action method? Check Request.Form if your form values passed here?

Comment: I enters into the method, but all atributes on the parameter are null.How do I check the Request.Form?

Comment: As an option you cam make var form = Request.Form; in your action and check if in from collection exist your values from view. Or you can Add Watch Request.Form while debugging and see this values

Comment: Also what type of model you View has? It should be @model = RealtyViewModel

Comment: form retrieved the Address and Details field, but,for some reason, not the manager fields. How do I make it so the values are stored in model? Or at least what could be missing on the manager fields that makes it not go into the form reques?

Comment: Yeah, that's the model it has, RealtyViewModel

Comment: id like to see your Edit action method signature that comes up with null param

Comment: I added it to the original question.

Comment: Do you have any additional javascript code on your page that could prevent expected normal form submission?

Comment: Nope. In fact a similar View that someone else made on the same project works fine. But even doing the exact same stuff gets me nowhere.

Comment: I have to go now, but if there's another idea what could this be, I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: I think you're values to 2 differents model on your view there is a using package @model solution.project.Models.RealtyViewModel
Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Try remove hidden fields from this form

```
<div class="row-fluid metro">
<div class="span2 offset4">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Realty", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Details</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Details)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Details)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Manager</label>
            <div class="controls">
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Manager.Id, Model.Managers)

               </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Realty")"><button type="button" class="btn">Cancelar</button></a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I did that and the situation is still the same.